# Taking the connection string value from textbox

Tags: sql, winforms, connection-string, database-connection

In one class I have defined the connection string like this

```
  SqlConnectionStringBuilder objConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            objConnectionString.DataSource = localServer; ;
            objConnectionString.UserID = userName;
            objConnectionString.Password = password;
            objConnectionString.InitialCatalog = selectedDatabase;
```

where local server = txtHost;--DataSource
      userName = txtUsername;
      password = txtPassword;

But in my another project I want to access the controls of that project

Currently I am connected with the db like this

```
  using(var sConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]))
```

But I want to make it such that it would take the value directly from the textboxes used in another project

Waiting for your suggestions .....Can It be done..

Answer (score 0):

You will not bne abble to do this, unless you pass the actual controls to the method in the other project.

Why not rather pass the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` object that you set up before hand to the method being called?

Answer (score 0):

In your form with the textbox you will need to create Properties to access the values from the form, e.g.

```
public string Server 
{
   get
   {
      return this.txtHost.Text;
   }
}
```

You will also need to pass a reference of the Form to your other Project, either by referencing the project, or using an shared interface between the two.

In your project where you want to build the connection string, you will need some way of receiving the reference to the Form, such as

```
public void RunMyQuery(MyForm form)
{
   var objConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
   objConnectionString.DataSource = form.Server; 
}
```

If you have time, consider creating a new project which contain shared interfaces, so you could create an interface such as

```
public interface IConnectionStringPartProvider
{
   string Server { get; }
   ... other parts
}
```

and implement this interface on your form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IConnectionStringPartProvider
```

Then you would not need to reference you form project in your logic class, just let both projects reference the shared project.

This way, your query method could be replaced with

```
public void RunMyQuery(IConnectionStringPartProvider provider)
{
   var objConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
   objConnectionString.DataSource = provider.Server; 
}
```